# SQL Select: subset of same table

Tags: sql, subquery

I have three related tables (students, classes, enrollments) (one student can have multiple enrollments and one class can have multiple enrollments) from which I need to select all students that are enrolled in classes (x,y,z) but not in classes (a, b, c).  How can I structure my query to achieve this?

Comment: Impossible to give a precise info without the schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree that we need more information to be honest. Something like this should work. Another way would be two queries and using the `MINUS` keyword to get all results from the first query (students in classes x, y and z), except the results from the second query (students in classes a, b and c).

Selecting all students that are in ALL of classes x, y and z, and in NONE of classes a, b and c.

```
SELECT * FROM Students s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Enrollment
    WHERE studentId = s.StudentId AND ClassId = 'x')
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Enrollment
    WHERE studentId = s.StudentId AND ClassId = 'y')
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Enrollment
    WHERE studentId = s.StudentId AND ClassId = 'z')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Enrollment
    WHERE studentId = s.StudentId AND ClassId IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: Great, this did the trick.  One question though...why did you create a WHERE EXISTS for each ClassId instead of using IN(x,y,z) as you did in the WHERE NOT EXISTS?

Comment: Because if I did that, it would give the students that are in ANY of the classes x, y or z, rather than ALL of the classes x,y and z.

Answer (score 1):

Supposed DDL (just to introduce names):

```
create table student ( s_id numeric, name varchar );
create table class ( c_id numeric, name varchar );
create table enrollment ( s_id numeric, c_id numeric );
```

1. Select ids of students not in a, b or c

   ```
   select s_id from enrollments where c_id not in
       (select c_id from class where name in ('a', 'b', 'c');
   ```
2. Select ids of students in x, y or z

   ```
   select s_id from enrollments where c_id in
       (select c_id from class where name in ('x', 'y', 'z');
   ```
3. Combine it

   ```
   select * from students where
       s_id in (select s_id from enrollments where c_id in
           (select c_id from class where name in ('x', 'y', 'z') and
       s_id not in (select s_id from enrollments where c_id in
           (select c_id from class where name in ('a', 'b', 'c');
   ```